# Empacotar codigo em python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Opa galera , beleza?

Então, eu terminei um projeto que contém só um arquivo .py que importa as seguintes bibliotecas :

dlib
face_recognition

E quero exportar esse código para que OUTROS LINUX , somente para linux, possam simplesmente baixar o código e executar um "python3 meucodigo.py" e o script se excute normalmente sem a necessidade de instalar todas as bibilhotecas importadas no código.

Teria como?

Versão do projeto: Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

É possível, mas, para isso, terá que abandonar o status de *"um projeto que contém só um arquivo .py"*; você terá que incluir outras coisas. Felizmente existe uma ferramenta para isso incluída a partir do python 3.5, o [módulo `zipapp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html):

A forma de usar é a seguinte:

```
$ python -m zipapp meucodigo -m "meucodigo:main"
```

Isso vai gerar um arquivo `meucodigo.pyz` com todas as bibliotecas que precisar embutidas, e pode ser executado diretamente com:

```
$ python meucodigo.pyz
```

No exemplo acima o código precisa estar em uma função chamada `main`; [Leia a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html) para mais opções.

Comment: @GustavodeOliveira seu comando está errado; não deveria ter `.py` ali. Leia a documentação.